# python code to c++ lib or dll

Tags: c++, python, dll

I have some python code that I want to use from C++, I want to build it in lib or dll? how can I do it?
code have dependencies:

```
import socket
import string
import struct
import sys
```

and maybe PIL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can use cython and write [thin wrapper to export it to C](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c)

Cython lib `helloWorld.pyx`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".") #yourlib is in current folder
import yourlib #you can import any python module

cdef public void helloWorld():
    print "Hello World Cython!"
    yourlib.helloWorld("Python")

cdef public int my_sum(int x, int y):
    return x*x+y

from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef public string testString( string sx, string sy ):
    x = int(sx.c_str())
    y = int(sy.c_str())
    ret= "%d*%d+%d=%d"%(x,x,y,my_sum(x,y))
    cdef char* ret2= ret
    return string( ret2 )
```

Compile with cython (create `helloWorld.cpp`, `helloWorld.h`):

```
    cython --cplus helloWorld.pyx
```

Your code `program.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"
#include "helloWorld.h" // it's cpp header so remove __PYX_EXTERN_C (bug)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize(); //start python interpreter
    inithelloWorld(); //run module helloWorld
    helloWorld();
    std::cout << testString("6","6") << std::endl; #it's fast!
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
    g++ program.cpp helloWorld.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7
    ./a.out
    Hello World Cython!
    Hello World Python!
    6*6+6=42
```

## Another way is to use [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html)

Your code `program.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::object sys = boost::python::import("sys");
    sys.attr("path").attr("append")(".");
    boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("yourlib");
    main_module.attr("helloWorld")("boost_python");
    boost::python::object ret= main_module.attr( "my_sum" )( 10, 10 );
    std::cout << boost::python::extract<char const*>(ret) << std::endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
    g++ program.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -lpython_boost
    ./a.out
    Hello World boost_python!
    10*10+10=110
```

Comment: maybe you give me some simple example?

# hello.py
<code>
def my_sum(x,y):
    print "Hello World!"
    return x*x+y
<code>

how to call this code from c++?

something like

code C++

<code>
int sum= py.my_sum(x,y);
<code>

Comment: thanks for example! it works, but how to access to method of the class?
`code`class class_cl:
def myadd(a,b):
 print("hell0 add")
 return a*a+b

Comment: You mean for second example? `boost::python::object ret= main_module.attr("class_cl")().attr("myadd")(1,2)`. It works in order: get reference to the class, create instance, get `myadd` method and call it with 1,2.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check how to embed python in another application (http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html).

Comment: if I use this approach and I want to run my programm on another computer I must have python interpretator installed?

Comment: @mrgloom Well yes, but that's true for absolutely any kind of cpython code. Never tried (for embedded code), but I'd think you can use freeze or similar tools to package only the necessary files into your application, I don't see any reason why not. You also have to include the right libs for the interpreter with your c program obviously

Comment: it sounds very complicated to me.I just want to put python code into lib or dll(build it only once and don't use interpretator in future) and have access to it from my c++ code (main program). maybe there are some examples on the web?

Comment: @mrgloom: no, if you embed Python into your application, you don't need Python installed on the target machine. You just need to distribute the Python DLL and all the Python modules you require (these can be placed in a single .zip) with your application

Comment: yes, I manged to do it by placing pithon27.dll and Lib with .py files with my project, I know I can distribute it all with something like installshield, but is there a way to build it in one .exe file?